# Não consigo achar uma resolução para esse erro

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um programa em C# e ele está dando MUITOS *bugs* diferentes, eu vou mandar todos aqui, da seguinte maneira:

Código
Erro:
Descrição:

Então vamos lá.

```
internal AcessoAdd()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

> Erro: `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:` 'Erro ao criar identificador de janela.'

Correção: alterei internal para public

Descrição: esse código já estava ai, eu tentei formatar o PC como recomendaram, tentei mexer no regedit e aumentar a quantidade de identificadores de janela permitidos, mas nada adianta.

```
UsuarioForm usuForm = new UsuarioForm();
```

> Erro: `System.StackOverflowException`

Descrição: UsuarioForm como o próprio nome já diz, é um form, eu crio uma variável para depois abri-lo porem esse erro acontece e já tentei de tudo também pra fazer funcionar.

Por enquanto é isso, provavelmente terá mais depois de corrigir esse, mas alguém sabe me responder como resolver esses dois?

Código do UsuarioForm:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PecsCon
{
public partial class UsuarioForm
{

    public UsuarioAdd usuAdd = new UsuarioAdd();
    public AcessoAdd acAdd = new AcessoAdd();

    internal UsuarioForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string idgrid;
    public string funcidgrid;
    public string logingrid;
    public string senhagrid;
    public int deletadogrid;
    public int op;
    private void Usuario_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MdiParent = FormPrincipal.DefaultInstance;
        this.Dock = DockStyle.None;

        //variavel para utilizar a classe
        BancoUsuario bncusu = new BancoUsuario();

        rbTodos.Checked = true;
        //preenche o datagridview
        bncusu.PreencheDataGrid(DataGridViewUsu, op);



    }

    private void ButtonX4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        acAdd.Show();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idgrid))
        {

            acAdd.cboxUsuario.SelectedValue = idgrid;

        }


    }

    private void usuCadastro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        usuAdd.add_update = 1;

        usuAdd.Show();


    }

    private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BancoUsuario bncusu = new BancoUsuario();

        bncusu.ProcuraTuplaUsu(ref DataGridViewUsu, procuraUsu, op);
    }

    private void rbDesativados_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbDesativados.Checked == true)
        {
            op = 2;


            //variavel para utilizar a classe
            BancoUsuario bncusu = new BancoUsuario();

            //preenche o datagridview
            bncusu.PreencheDataGrid(DataGridViewUsu, op);
        }
    }

    private void rbTodos_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbTodos.Checked == true)
        {
            op = 3;


            //variavel para utilizar a classe
            BancoUsuario bncusu = new BancoUsuario();

            //preenche o datagridview
            bncusu.PreencheDataGrid(DataGridViewUsu, op);
        }
    }

    private void rbAtivos_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbAtivos.Checked == true)
        {
            op = 1;


            //variavel para utilizar a classe
            BancoUsuario bncusu = new BancoUsuario();

            //preenche o datagridview
            bncusu.PreencheDataGrid(DataGridViewUsu, op);
        }
    }

    private void usuDeletar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BancoUsuario bncusu = new BancoUsuario();

        bncusu.DeletaUsu(Convert.ToInt32(this.idgrid), op);

    }

    public void DataGridViewUsu_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {

            DataGridViewRow row = null;

            row = this.DataGridViewUsu.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            BancoUsuario bncusu = new BancoUsuario();



            idgrid = row.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
            funcidgrid = row.Cells["Id Funcionario"].Value.ToString();
            logingrid = row.Cells["Login"].Value.ToString();
            senhagrid = row.Cells["Senha"].Value.ToString();
            deletadogrid = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Deletado"].Value);

        }

    }

    private void usuVizualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BancoUsuario bncusu = new BancoUsuario();

        usuAdd.add_update = 2;

        bncusu.buscaUsu(Convert.ToInt32(idgrid), Convert.ToInt32(funcidgrid), ref logingrid, ref senhagrid, ref deletadogrid, ref usuAdd.NomeComboBox, ref usuAdd.loginText, ref usuAdd.senhaText, usuAdd.cbAtivo.Checked);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Só com este código não tem como ajudar. Seria bom [edit] e colocar o código de `UsuarioForm` também.

Comment: Irei  editar agora.

Comment: a criação de variavel

        "AcessoAdd acAdd = new AcessoAdd();"

Tambem dá erro, porem acho que é por causa do primeiro erro

Answer (score 1):

Verifica se esta importando as namespaces.

As classes **UsuarioAdd** e **AcessoAdd** ambos estão em uma namespaces diferente da **PecsCon**.

Se, por exemplo, elas estiverem em um namespces chamada **Usuarios** e **Acessos** respectivamente, tente isso:

```
    using NomeDoProjeto.Usuarios;
    using NomeDoProjeto.Acessos;
```

Comment: A unica coisa que apareceu aqui é "using PecsCon.My;" e "using PecsCon,Properties", as duas estão na namespace PecsCon

Comment: As classes UsuarioAdd e AcessoAdd estão dentro dessas namespaces?

Comment: UsuarioAdd e AcessoAdd estão na namespace PecsCon

Comment: Arrumei o primeiro erro, eu mudei de "Internal AcessoAdd()" ... para "Public AcessoAdd()..."

Comment: Qual é o outro erro?

Comment: o segundo que ta na pergunta, corrigi agr falta o erro que esta dando em UsuarioForm usuForm = new UsuarioForm(), o erro System.StackOverflowException

Comment: Poste as classes UsuarioAdd e AcessoAdd que conforme vc disse, estão na mesma namespace.

Answer (score 0):

remova

`internal UsuarioForm()`

coloque

```
public  UsuarioForm()
```